# Router-Link calling in the url but not displaying the page always main showing

Tags: vue.js

i am a newbie in vuejs. I wanted to display the other page when clicking the link in the main page. However i already put the router-link tag. but when running in dev and click the url is adding but the page is not redirecting. Kindly help me. Thank you.

index.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)
export const constantRouterMap = [{
        path: '/main',
        component: () =>
            import ('../views/main/main'),
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        path: "/about",
        component: () =>
            import ('../views/about/about'),
    }
]

export default new Router({
    // mode: 'history',
    routes: constantRouterMap
})

export const asyncRoutes = []
```

main.vue

```html
<template>

  <div id="main">
    <router-link to="/about"> 
        About
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

about.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is about page</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Link showing when clicking the router link

[image: Link showing when clicking the router link]

Comment: So you're saying you initially load `/main` and see the _"About"_ link but when you click it, it goes to `/main?redirect=%2Fabout`? Nothing in the code shown would cause that to happen

Comment: yes when i click the about link does not show any only show the main page

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on CodeSandbox or JSfiddle ?